# How can I break on labels using react-bootstrap-table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

My table is:

```
<BootstrapTable data={props.workbooks} striped={true} hover={true}>
  <TableHeaderColumn
    dataField="id"
    isKey={true}
    dataAlign="center"
    columnClassName={ props.tdClassFormatter }
    width='50px'>
    ID
  </TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="createdAt" width='130px' dataFormat={(cDate) => moment(cDate).format('MMM D, \'YY (h:mm a)')}>Created On</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="status" width='90px' hidden={props.minimized}>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="subject" width='90px' hidden={props.minimized}>Subject</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="results" dataFormat={this.resultsFormatter} dataAlign="center">
    Total /
    <span className="text-info">Attempted</span> /
    <span className="text-success">✓</span> /
    <span className="text-danger">✗</span> /
    <span className="text-muted">Skip</span>
  </TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="skills" dataFormat={this.skillsFormatter}>Skills</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" dataFormat={this.actionFormatter} dataAlign="center" hidden={props.minimized}></TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

And `this.skillsFormatter` is:

```
  skillsFormatter(skills) {
    const skillHTML = skills.map((skill, index) => {
      return (
        <span key={index}>
          <Label bsStyle="default">{skill}</Label>&nbsp;
        </span>
      )
    })
    return (
      <div className="text-center">
        {skillHTML}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

But I want the labels to break on new lines instead of this:
[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the CSS style `overflow-wrap: break-word` to your `skillsFormatter`. This "should" cause those skills elements to wrap.

```
  skillsFormatter(skills) {
    const skillHTML = skills.map((skill, index) => {
      return (
        <span key={index}>
          <Label bsStyle="default">{skill}</Label>&nbsp;
        </span>
      )
    })
    return (
      <div className="text-center" style={{overflowWrap:'break-word'}}>
        {skillHTML}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

You will probably also have to set a fixed width on this column as well.

```
<TableHeaderColumn dataField="skills" width="300px" dataFormat={this.skillsFormatter}>Skills</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Comment: Any way to do it WITHOUT a fixed width?

Comment: Try using `width="100%"` in the `TableHeaderColumn`, instead of a number. Then the width will be inherited from the parent. Hopefully that works.

Comment: Tried it, with a fixed with and `100%`. No dice either way.

Comment: @shamoon: is it possible for you to set up a fiddle for this? Will be easier to troubleshoot with a working example.